# How to enable if else matching line/indicator in Automation Anywhere?

Tags: automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I am using AA for almost 6 months and I found that by default I am not able to see any lines/dotted lines/indicator which basically shows which `if` *statement* is being matched for `else` *statement*. This is usually shown as a dotted line in other IDEs. I really need this specially if the condition branches out and it's really difficult for me to find out the matching if else clause. Is this feature available in AA or something to be set in properties?[image]

Comment: I've been frustrated about this too. As far as I know, it's impossible, but good of you to put the question out there. Maybe someone knows!

Comment: not available in version 10, but getting introduce in version 11 LTE, as an alternate you can add comments at the start and end to make it differ

Comment: @SyedUmarAhmed for real? v11 already integrated this feature?

Answer (score 1):

It would have been a great feature to have for faster debugging.

Nonetheless at the moment the only way to differentiate is by paying attention to the Indentation between the `If` - `Else` blocks

For e.g Nested IF

```
If (Main Condition)
{
}
  If(Condition)
  {
  }
  Else(Condition)
  {
  }
Else (Condition)
{
}
```

P.S : Automation-Anywhere does not have the capabilities of a Text Editor or an IDE simply because in AA we are executing a set of drag and drop commands from Command library.
Although a highlight would have been a great feature to offer !